# How to convert base64 into binary stream using javascript?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, binary, base64

The uploading images API needs binary stream. I've tried new `FileReader()` and its `readAsBinaryString()` method, but it doesn't work! It seems that binary string and binary stream are not the same thing, so I changed my way and tried `readAsDataURL()` method (cause I need to preview images) and now I want to know:

1) how to convert `base64` into binary stream using **js**?

When I use `readAsBinaryString()`,the respond is as follow (data A):

[image: binary_string]

But the API needs something like this (data B):

[image: binary_stream]

2) Anybody know how to convert dataA ( picture above ) into dataB ( picture down )?

Comment: _"I've tried new FileReader() and its *readAsBinaryString()*method, but it doesn't work!"_ What do you mean by "binary stream"?

Comment: when you say "it doesn't work" - do you get errors in the console for example?

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing the api need a hex view `(data B)` when you say that the api needs a binary stream - which one is it?

Answer (score 9):

This is how you convert a base64 into *binary stream*

```js
var base64 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

fetch(base64)
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.body instanceof ReadableStream)
})
```

**Note:** This only works in Blink atm, could use [Screw-FileReader](https://github.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader) and web-streams-polyfill to turn any blob into a *byte stream* if you like

But what i really think you wanna do is to turn a base64 into a blob (binary container) and then upload it to a api as binary (not as base64) if that is true then this is just a duplicate of [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript) and then it's just a mather of sending it with ajax to a server

```js
var base64 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

fetch(base64)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => {
  console.log("here is your binary: ", blob)

  // now upload it
  fetch(api, {method: 'POST', body: blob})
})
```

Getting the base64 in the first place is really impractical and should be dealt with before using arrayBuffer, or blob
If you for example getting it from canvas - try using `canvas.toBlob` instead of `toDataUrl`

Comment: i am working on React Native App, fetch method is working fine for ios but not working for android!
is there anything alternative to convert base64 into blob?